# the hidden expression for table contains an error: Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I am trying to hide an SSRS column based on the ReportServerURL.  If it is on site A it will be hidden but if it is on Site B it will be shown.  This is the expression that I am using in the Column Visibility property.  `=IIf(Globals!ReportServerUrl.IndexOf("devrxanalytics") >= 0, false, true)`

The problem is that it works once it is deployed to either sharepoint site, but when I try to view it in Visual Studio under preview, I get the following error:

> the hidden expression for table contains an error: Object variable or
>   with block variable not set

Not a big deal since it works on the site but how would I resolve this so that I may view the report in Preview mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIf(ISNOTHING(Globals!ReportServerUrl) OR
Globals!ReportServerUrl.IndexOf("devrxanalytics") >= 0, false, true)
```

This expression performs the following logic, if `ReportServerUrl` global variable is null (report generated from visual studio) or  `ReportServerUrl` contains `devrxanalytics`, don't hide the column.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly!  I still get the above error, however when I change the connection string to another development site I also get the following code:

Comment: (For some reason I was able to edit the above post with the error message) Thanks for getting back to me so quickly!  I still get the above error, however when I change the connection string to another development site I also get the following error in preview mode for the other dev site:  "The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota"

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution, tested in VS2013 with SSRS 2008 R2 compatibility

```
=IIf(ISNOTHING(Globals!ReportServerUrl) ORELSE
    Globals!ReportServerUrl.IndexOf("devrxanalytics") >= 0, false, true)
```

Visual basic since .NET version by default evaluates all the expressions. If you want to have lazy or short-circuit evaluation, then you have to use special operators **ORELSE** or **ANDALSO**.